# Pages with parent pages giving 404 errors

Tags: permalinks

I have 300 pages website. Suddenly all pages with parent pages are giving 404 error. But when i set no parent then page is working fine.

Even i changed Permalinks `Settings -> Permalinks` and choose `Post Name` then hit **SAVE**

Please let me know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change the first character of slug to capital and try to run child pages and let me know if this works or as same it is